# PyAutoGUI can not detect FB approve button under the video, yet it works fine with buttons under photos. Any suggestions?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

I have created simple program for automating post approvals in group. Basically I open post approval page on facebook then start program and it finds Approve button using pg.locateCenterOnScreen then it clicks on it approving post and then scrolls down so another button comes into view, waits 5 minute and then repeats the process.

It works fine without any trouble with Approve button that is under the photo, but if it has to approve video it fails. For some reason it can not detect Approve button under the video and throws error: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

It is quite simple and badly coded since I have one day of experience in Python. Below is the code sample, and photos from FB.

```
import pyautogui as pg

import time

count = 0

while count < 50:

    x, y = pg.locateCenterOnScreen('butt.png', grayscale = True)

    pg.moveTo(x, y, 2)
    pg.click(x, y)
    pg.scroll(-190)
    time.sleep(300)
    count = + 1
```

Links: [Button with photo above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaTw5.jpg), [Button with video above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGarT.png), [Error image in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAVDS.png), [butt.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N9hR.png)

Comment: What is butt.png then?

Comment: Its a screen shot of the approve button, so locateCenterOnScreen can find that button on screen.

Comment: Sorry for really late reply, but which one is butt.png

Comment: I didn't posted it first time, but now its added with other photos in attachment.